# Add Xamarin.iOS view cell background color and corner radius

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add corner radius cell on **selected row**. I can do it for all but not selected one.

This part of code is not working.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(ViewCellItemSelectedCustomRenderer))]
namespace PawsApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ViewCellItemSelectedCustomRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        private UIView bgView;

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell viewCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            if (viewCell != null)
            {
                if (bgView == null)
                {
                    bgView = new UIView(viewCell.SelectedBackgroundView.Bounds);
                    bgView.Layer.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#666495").ToCGColor();
                    bgView.Layer.CornerRadius = new nfloat(17.5);
                }

                viewCell.SelectedBackgroundView = bgView;            
            }
            return viewCell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try keeping the select/deselect status in the datasource object as a property and customise the cell view based on that property.

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: Hey dude, no i don't. Just skipped. But i will try again with your answer. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hey mate, thats works like a charm, thanks. But how can i provide to wrap selected word, i mean just long as word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(ViewCellItemSelectedCustomRenderer))]

You can add a subclass of `ViewCell` in forms and create it's custom renderer. Such as

```
public class CustomVeggieCell : ViewCell
{
    public CustomVeggieCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views
        var image = new Image();
        var nameLabel = new Label();
        var typeLabel = new Label();
        var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();
        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.Olive };

        //set bindings
        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        typeLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Type"));
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));

        //Set properties for desired design
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        horizontalLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
        nameLabel.FontSize = 24;

        //add views to the view hierarchy
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(typeLabel);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(verticaLayout);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image);

        // add to parent view
        View = horizontalLayout;
    }
}
```

I have share my [sample](https://github.com/luczha/ViewCellSample) on github .You can download it for testing.